# ReactJS Material UI - Issue with setting the hover border color of TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the hover border color of a TextField to a theme variable. However I found that the hover borderColor needs the "!important" tag to work, but I don't know how to add it to the theme variable?

So basically what I need to do is `borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main!important` somehow.

I made an example below, you can also check the codesandbox. Any suggestions are welcome!

```
  const style = {
    fieldset: {
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    },
    "&:hover fieldset": {
      //borderColor: "green!important" // works
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main // doesnt work
    }
  };

  return <TextField sx={style} />;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-robinson-17spqs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two edits:

1. You are setting the primary color to the border color when hovering which is the same color it has when it is in not-hovering mode! (both `primary.main`)
2. you can set `+ "!important"` to your code.

Try following, it works:

```
import { React } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#D20000",
      secondary: "green"
    }
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const style = {
    fieldset: {
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    },
    "&:hover fieldset": {
      //borderColor: "green!important" // works
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.secondary + "!important" // doesnt work
    }
  };

  return <TextField sx={style} />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think your first comment is entirely right, TextField has its own light gray normal color and hover color. If you set the border color, then the hover color is still default light gray. Anyway, this is exactly what I needed, I had no idea you could do that :)